# How to use in-page HTML anchors with hashbang URLs (in GWT)?

Tags: gwt, anchor, gwt-platform, hashbang, gwt-places

I have a little problem with implementing in-page HTML anchors while also having bookmarkable URLs via hashbang. The description is easy:

- I visit some URL of my application: http://www.mypage.com/Test.html#!mycontent

On this page there is a lot of text and I need some HTML anchors for navigation. In old-style HTML I'd write `<a href="#myAnchor">AnchorText</a>`.

- But when I click this link in my GWT application, the URL changes to: http://www.mypage.com/Test.html#myAnchor

GWT Platform recognized the change and throws me back to my `DefaultPlace`. That's clear because it can't associate the URL to a presenter.

So now the (simple) question is: How can I use in-page navigation while also having hashbang URLs?

Comment: Do you want the in-page navigation also be part of the history? Because whatever your solution will when you use old-style HTML tags they will become part of the history. So even if your code correctly works the browser will also put the in-page navigation on the history stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you construct your anchor?
In case you are doing it statically, why now just add the `!` to the href?:
 `<a href="!#myAnchor">AnchorText</a>`

**Update**:
Ok Instead of an normal `Anchor` you can use a `Hyperlink` or `InlineHyperlink` and set the `targetHistoryToken` value to **#!myAnchor**:

```
<g:InlineHyperlink ui:field="diversityLink" targetHistoryToken="!#myAnchor">MyAnchor</g:InlineHyperlink>
```